# CSS image background and overlay blocking link and text input click and focus

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have the following html and css:

```css
.icon-bar {
    width: 90px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    }

    #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -2;
    }

    #cover-photo {
    width:100%;height: 400px;    
    background:url('./assets/covers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    color:#fff;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12" id="cover-photo">
        <div id="overlay">

        </div>
        <div class="icon-bar col-md-push-10">
        <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a> 
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Now the background image is appearing, as well as the overlay div as expected, the div with the icon-bar class also appears in the front, but when I try to click one of the links inside that div it does not get the click, i have set a z-index of 100 for this div but it is unclickable, please assist me on this guys

Comment: For what your `#overlay` div?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: have you tried pointer events? `pointer-events: none;` on your image div

Comment: Your div with `overlay` id has `position: absolute, width: 100%; height: 100%`.
So, I think that it covers your second div which has `class="icon-bar col-md-push-10"`

Comment: @Jamie I just did, nothing happened, ArmKh, so what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got your point here. What's wrong in your code is where you position `<div id="overlay"></div>`

It should place after the end tag of `cover-photo`

I also rearrange your codes and modify some it.

My advise is not to make to have negative `z-index` instead use smaller to greater number to overlap the property of one element to another.

```css
#cover-photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: url('./assets/covers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    color: #fff;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5;
}

.icon-bar {
    width: 90px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}

#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="cover-photo">
        <div class="icon-bar col-md-push-10">
            <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though the overlay now covers almost the whole document, the z-index of the class 'icon-bar' is on top and links are click-able, thanks

Comment: great! glad it helps :)

Comment: I have changed the display of the overlay from fixed to absolute and it was nicely placed on the cover photo.

Comment: oh okay. at first, i tried to understand what you have asked and then it went to that code. I'm happy it helps you a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You can add `pointer-events: none` to the overlay div. This will allow clicking the links behind it.

Comment: You, my friend, are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

```
I think it is because of anchor tag it is inline tag 
try to make it inline-block so it will work.

Check below link

https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbhalerao/Ldot4y96/4/

Thanks,

Ashish Bhalerao
```